# react-native android-Markers with custom images

Tags: android, google-maps, react-native

Markers with custom images - images are not rendered in release but it is showing correctly in debug mode !!
any solution please ?

Comment: post your code.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with Android's image rendering library Fresco. No fixes were included in the latest releases of Fresco or React Native.

Refer to this issue for more information and workarounds: https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/1870

I ended up "fixing" (circumventing) this issue by not rendering images in markers/callouts on Android, but instead using a modal that pops up when a marker is pressed. You could use some conditional rendering to keep displaying the image on iOS, but not on Android.

Answer (score 0):

I have also struggled with this issue, read various posts in [react-native-maps/issues/1870](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/1870), and this is what seems to work for me (based on @outaTiME and @adlondon posts in the above link):

- Specifying image as a prop of Marker (instead of `<Image />` inside RN view within the Marker) seems to solve this problem for all Android versions. However, it is impossible to specify the image size (which is possible when using `<Image />`), which makes implementation more difficult - see [react-native-maps/issues/1167](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/1167)
- For Android versions below 7.0, you can use `<Image />`, but you must preload the images before using them in the marker. This can be done by rendering the marker images with size=0, before rendering the markers. What I did as a workaround, until I implement something better, is to delay the Map's display in 1-2 seconds, and start by rendering the 0-size images.

I also tried the following suggestion which didn't work for me:

- Using `<ImageBackground />` instead of `<Image />` (seems that it worked for some people)

Note: I am not sure about 7.0, it behaves differently on different devices, so the best approach is to use image props for it as well.

Answer (score -1):

Use below this code-

```
  key={marker.title}
  onPress={this.hideNearLocationPopup}
  >
  {marker.type === "fire"?
      <Image   source={require('../images/abc.png')} style = {{ width: 112, height: 25,borderRadius:3}}/>
      :
      <Image   source={require('../images/abc.png')} style = {{ width: 45, height: 25,borderRadius:3}}/>
      }
 </MapView.Marker>
```